# PowerShell ScriptBlock variable scope

Tags: powershell, scope, closures, scriptblock

I'm having trouble understanding scopes within `ScriptBlock`s.  I was counting on some kind of closure-like system, but I can't seem to get it working.

I have a `ScriptBlock` that takes a `param` and returns another `ScriptBlock`:

```
$sb1 = {
    Param($Message1);
    Write-Host $Message1;
    {
        Param($Message2);
        Write-Host ($Message1 + " " + $Message2);
    }
}
```

To get the inner `ScriptBlock` I can invoke `$sb1` with `$sb2 = & $sb1 -Message1 "Message1"`.  This echoes `Message1` so we know the `param` is bound.

Now I can invoke `$sb2` with `& $sb2 -Message2 "Message2"`.  I would have expected `Message1 Message2`, but it just writes `Message2` instead.

Is there any way to access the `$Message1` variable?  I can't use a local or script variable, because there will multiple instances of the inner scriptblock with different `$Message1`s.

This is the actual output from the actual shell:

```
PS C:\> $h1 = { Param($Message1); Write-Host $Message1; { Param($Message2); Write-Host ($Message1 + " " + $Message2); } }
PS C:\> $h2 = & $h1 -Message1 "Message1"
Message1
PS C:\> $h2
 Param($Message2); Write-Host ($Message1 + " " + $Message2);
PS C:\> & $h2 -Message2 "Message2"
 Message2
```

Comment: I'll update the question with what I'm actually running. It's very similar though.

Comment: Ah, missed the assignment of the return value. Okay, makes sense now :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to explicitly [create a closure](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/04/05/closures-in-powershell/):

```
$sb1 = {
    Param($Message1);
    Write-Host $Message1;
    {
        Param($Message2);
        Write-Host ($Message1 + " " + $Message2);
    }.GetNewClosure()
}
```

It then works for me:

```
PS> $2 = & $sb1 One
One
PS> & $2 Two
One Two
```

Comment: Okay, wow. That totally makes sense. I never knew ScriptBlock actually had a GetNewClosure method. Most languages aren't that explicit about closures :)

Comment: Having the choice can be nice sometimes. I have written scripts where I used scriptblocks just to access variables I knew were there and where having a closure would have been annoying. But yeah, usually it's either automatic or not supported at all :-)

Comment: Didn't know that either. Nice one!

Comment: And I have to admit, that's the first instance of currying I've seen in PowerShell. Never even occurred to me to do that :-)